# How to get a return value from click event on a jquery plugin element?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am creating a plugin which will be attached to a div and show up with few buttons. Now when these buttons are clicked, it will perform some calculation and return a value which will be stored in variable. Below is the probable scenario.

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
     /*---- Custom plugin is initialized ---------*/ 
     $('.mydiv').myPlugin();

      /*----- Click event on the buttons created by the plugin and attached to the div -----*/
      $('body').on('clicked','.myPluginButton',function()
      {
        var returnedValue = /* Here plugin calculated some data and returns a value which will be stored in this returnedValue variable for later use */
      });
   });
```

Please suggest the way forward for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So a couple more questions.  #1) you're binding on 'clicked' which is not a standard event.  Is that a typo?  #2) The event handler is only going to be getting the click event.  How exactly are you saying that the plugin is returning a value?

Comment: I really don't know how to achieve this. But my intention is to get some data from my plugin which is variable in nature depending upon which button is clicked. The return value will be stored in local variable for later use.

Comment: Without more details about how the plugin returns data, that's a very vague question.

Comment: Sir the plugin is going to return a simple integer. This integer will be derived from the attribute of the clicked button(Button created by the plugin) which is also an integer plus some store variable inside the plugin. I just don't know how can a plugin returns data upon an event on its element ( In this case, the button)

Comment: Again, event handlers do not return values.  It would be more appropriate for the plugin to be provided a callback.  Then when the event happens and the value is calculated, the plugin would then call the callback, passing in the value

Answer (score 1):

**In short,** you'll need something like this:

```
$('.mydiv').myPlugin({ // Pass options Object to plugin
  clicked: function(ev, data) {
    console.log(data); // Example accessing data Object
  }
});
```

Since you say your buttons are created by your plugin, let it be so!
Instead of creating listeners to `'body'`:

- Create a **plugin options Method** (callback) called `clicked`
- Use `.call()` to pass `this`, `...arguments`, and a `data` Object
- Use your plugin methods when instantiating your plugin

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function(opt) {

  const settings = $.extend({
    namespace: 'myPlugin',
    clicked: function() {},
  }, opt);
  
  this.each(function(index, el) {
    const $el = $(el); // Your target element
    
    const data = { // Some data you want to pass on click
      index: index,
      el: el,
      $el: $el,
      test: `This is ${settings.namespace} ${index}`
    };
    
    // The button created by the plugin and attached to the Element 
    $('<button/>', {
      appendTo: $el,
      class: settings.namespace+'-button',
      text: 'CLICK ME',
    }).on(`click.${settings.namespace}`, function() {
      if (settings.clicked && typeof settings.clicked === 'function') {
        return settings.clicked.call(this, ...arguments, data);
      }
    });
    
  });
  
  return this;
};


jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

   // Custom plugin is initialized
   $('.mydiv').myPlugin({
     // Click event on the buttons created by the plugin and attached to the div 
     clicked: function(ev, data) {
       console.log(ev.type); // Example accessing $Event Object
       console.log(this.textContent); // Accessible this reference to Button
       console.log(ev.target.tagName); // Example accessing target Element (Button)
       console.log(data.test); // Example accessing data
       console.log(`Parent ID is: ${data.el.id}`); // Example accessing parent ID from data
     }
   });

 });
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_1">THIS IS MYDIV_1</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_2">THIS IS MYDIV_2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or with less code for sake of readability, and by using the jQuery.Event.data Object:

```js
$.fn.myPlugin = function(opt) {

  const settings = $.extend({
    clicked: function() {},
  }, opt);
  
  return this.each(function(index, el) {

    const data = {
      index: index,
      text: `Clicked ${index}`
    };

    $('<button/>', {
      appendTo: el,
      class: 'myPlugin-button',
      text: 'CLICK',
    }).on('click', data, settings.clicked);
    
  });
};

$('.mydiv').myPlugin({
  clicked: function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.data.index);
    console.log(ev.data.text);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_1">THIS IS MYDIV_1</div>
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv_2">THIS IS MYDIV_2</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mr. Taplar and Mr. Roko thank you very much for your support. I have sorted out the issue with the guidance both of you provided. Thanks again.